# Is there a Stack Exchange community in which one can ask subjective and possibly open-ended programming questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation, subjective

I am working on a Web application, and I was looking for a reasonable implementation for one of its backend services. I wanted to ask the community if they have done something similar and if so how does their implementation work?

This is a subjective and possibly open-ended question, hence Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask this question.

Is there a Stack Exchange community in which one can ask suchlike questions?

Comment: The 4th place suggests possible new sites.  It does not answer the OPs question.  SE's definition of duplicate seems to have morphed into "somewhat related".

Answer (score 3):

You have at least three options

1. There are countless programming forums on the web, outside the SE network. Ask there.
2. Find a suitable [SO chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), and ask there.
3. Rephrase the question as asking for an open-source implementation of the backend service, with some of your specific requirements, and ask on the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) - please read [the guidelines on how to ask](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/353), first.

Comment: 1 and 2 are of course two other alternatives, but I was specifically looking for a SE community that does not prohibit subjective/open-ended questions. I also do not like the idea of rephrasing a question just for the sake of bypassing some guidelines. I am not interested in software recommendations as I am looking for possible architectures, algorithms, etc. Judging by your answer, I gather a subjective/open-ended SE community for programming questions does not exist or you don't know any.

Comment: @Behrang SE is just not made for that.

Comment: @Behrang my idea behind (3) was that once you've got open-source implementations, you can look at their architectures and algorithms. As bjb568 and the sites' FAQs will tell you, the SE Q&A format, and the network ethos, is not designed for subjective or open-ended questions.